# How to use a JSON mapping file to generate a new DataFrame in Spark using Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have two `DataFrame`s, `DF1` and `DF2`, and a JSON file which I need to use as a mapping file to create another dataframe (`DF3`).

DF1:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|    100|   John| Mumbai|
|    101|   Alex|  Delhi|
|    104|  Divas|Kolkata|
|    108|  Jerry|Chennai|
+-------+-------+-------+
```

DF2:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+
|column4|    column5|column6|
+-------+-----------+-------+
|     S1|        New|    xxx|
|     S2|        Old|    yyy|
|     S5|replacement|    zzz|
|    S10|        New|    ppp|
+-------+-----------+-------+
```

Apart from this one mapping file I am having in JSON format which will be use to generate DF3.

Below is the JSON mapping file:

```
{"targetColumn":"newColumn1","sourceField1":"column2","sourceField2":"column4"}
{"targetColumn":"newColumn2","sourceField1":"column7","sourceField2":"column5"}
{"targetColumn":"newColumn3","sourceField1":"column8","sourceField2":"column6"}
```

So from this JSON file I need to create `DF3` with a column available in the `targetColumn` section of the mapping and it will check the source column if it is present in DF1 then it map to `sourceField1` from `DF1` otherwise `sourceField2` from `DF2`.

Below is the expected output.

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
|newColumn1| newColumn2|newColumn3|
+----------+-----------+----------+
|      John|        New|       xxx|
|      Alex|        Old|       yyy|
|     Divas|replacement|       zzz|
|     Jerry|        New|       ppp|
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Any help here will be appropriated.

Comment: what have you tried Divas?

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql  -> from_json + schema, all build in

Comment: @Pavel Can you give one example how I can implement this in my code? as I am new in spark

Comment: ds.withColumn("my_json_column", from_json( col("my_json_column"), validJsonSchema)

Comment: @Pavel This is not working. Can you explain what is my_json_column here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the `JSON` and create the below `List` of custom objects

```
case class SrcTgtMapping(targetColumn:String,sourceField1:String,sourceField2:String)
val srcTgtMappingList=List(SrcTgtMapping("newColumn1","column2","column4"),SrcTgtMapping("newColumn2","column7","column5"),SrcTgtMapping("newColumn3","column8","column6"))
```

Add dummy `index column` to both the `dataframes` and join both the `dataframes` based on `index column`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1WithIndex=df1.withColumn("index",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
val df2WithIndex=df2.withColumn("index",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
val joinedDf=df1WithIndex.join(df2WithIndex,df1WithIndex.col("index")===df2WithIndex.col("index"))
```

Create the `query` and execute it.

```
val df1Columns=df1WithIndex.columns.toList
val df2Columns=df2WithIndex.columns.toList
val query=srcTgtMappingList.map(stm=>if(df1Columns.contains(stm.sourceField1)) joinedDf.col(stm.sourceField1).alias(stm.targetColumn) else joinedDf.col(stm.sourceField2).alias(stm.targetColumn))
val output=joinedDf.select(query:_*)
output.show
```

Sample Output:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
|newColumn1| newColumn2|newColumn3|
+----------+-----------+----------+
|      John|        New|       xxx|
|      Alex|        Old|       yyy|
|     Jerry|        New|       ppp|
|     Divas|replacement|       zzz|
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Hope this approach will help you

Comment: Thanks for providing this awesome solution but my requirement is to do in Scala instead of SparkSQl. So can you please help me here to do same thing using Scala only?

Comment: Hi @DivasNikhra , I modified my solution for dataframes only

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this solution. This is exactly I was looking :)

Comment: Can you please help me in this question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928103/how-to-create-dataframe-from-listmap-based-on-condition